Outdoor navigation without slam and own extended kalman filter
Good morning everyone, I’m working on my project of outdoor navigation with a robot on ros melodic. I created an extended kalman filter that uses the location provided by odometry for the forecast part and a gps for the update part. The idea, however, is to create a frame map in the position where the robot is located (almost always from just turned on and where the odom frame is located) and update the transform between these two frames (similar to what is done in robot_localization package). Finally I want to guide the robot using a satellite map of the area where the robot is located but I don’t understand how to position the frame map in such a way that it is consistent with the real location of the robot. So my robot knows where to locate itself in the frame map but how do I place this frame on the map?
Thanks in advance to whoever will answer me

You want to keep a separate frame map that's derived from odometry, vs. a satellite map that's pinned to GPS?  Why?  Why not just have one (lat-lon or ECEF) coordinate system?
